# Make [downcast] a synonym of [downcasting]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

While flipping through tags, I noticed that [downcast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/downcast) and [downcasting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/downcasting) are currently two separate tags.

They already have the same tag wiki:

> Downcasting permits an object of a superclass type to be treated as an
>   object of any subclass type.

[downcast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/downcast) currently has 77 questions tagged, while [downcasting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/downcasting) has 394. Can we make [downcast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/downcast) a synonym of [downcasting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/downcasting)?

Comment: But what if I'm just `downcast` because something in my code isn't working????????? Huh?

Comment: I agree. I don't really know the rules for this, but I'd even think about deleting the downcast tag. Migrating 41 questions should not be a big problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another point to note is that both the tags have exactly the same related tags, and in the same order, which also a subtle hint that the two tags can be used interchangeably.

I made [downcasting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/downcasting) (x394) a synonym of [downcast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/downcast) (x77), and there are now 471 questions in total.